# What is failing in my form validation function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops, validation

So I've tried making a function that loops through the elements of a form and checks the length of the elements, and if so, change the class so they can be styled differently. The code I have I assumed would work, and I'm not getting any errors in my console, so I can't pinpoint what is going wrong exactly. If someone could tell me why this won't work or how to fix it that would be awesome! Thankyou!

```
function validate_form(){
 var form = document.forms['form_name']; //store form into a variable
 var validated = true; // store return value for onsubmit attribute
     for(i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++){
      if(form.elements[i].value.length){  // check if form elements are empty
           form.elements[i].className = "validate_failed";  // if elements are empty, add a class that will style them
           validated = false;
           return validated;
    } else{
        validated = true;
        return validated;
    }
    return validated;
}
return validated;
}
```

Comment: It could be a missing `var i;` and you are returning way too often.

Comment: Wouldnt the loop set i at the beginning of the occurence?

Comment: What is the problem? What exactly happens? Does the style not get applied? Does the style get applied at the wrong time? Please be specific.

Comment: Absolutely nothing happens! The form is submitted as if the function is not even called, but in my form i have     onsubmit="return validate_form()" in my form element. So i dont understand,

Comment: can you put up alert before your for loop start and see if its even hitting the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function validate_form(){
  var form = document.forms['form_name']; //store form into a variable
  for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++){
    if(form.elements[i].value.length===0){  // check if form elements are empty
      form.elements[i].className = "validate_failed";  // if elements are empty, add a class that will style them
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

assuming

```
<form onsubmit="return validate_form()" ...
```

or make it all unobtrusive

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms['form_name'].onsubmit=function() {
    for(var i=0; i<this.elements.length; i++){
      this.elements[i].className = "";
      if(this.elements[i].value.length===0){  // check if form elements are empty
        this.elements[i].className = "validate_failed";  // if elements are empty, add a class that will style them
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly it! Actually I was changing my original code around while waiting for more answers on here so I got it right before I read your answer! But our code is identical so that means we both were right. Thankyou very much for trying to help out!

Answer (score 1):

Because your are returning `validated` during the first run through of the loop, you'll only ever check the first element of the form.  You'll just want to set `validated`, and return it after the loop (or return when you first set it to false, depending on what you want to do).

Also, like Joe commented, you should have `var i` instead of just `i` so that `i` is not global.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work for empty element

```
if(!form.elements[i].value.length){
```

OR

```
if(form.elements[i].value.length === 0){
```